# Bounded derivatives implies taylor series (introductory analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

I've been asked to show that if $f$ is in $C^{\infty}$, and there exist $L>0$ such that $\vert f^{(n)}(x)\vert \leq L$, then for any $x_0,x$, $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^{n}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}$$

I'm not sure  of how to prove this, initially I though that the fact that the function is infinitely differentiable implied the existence and equality of the series expansion, however we saw some examples like $h(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ when $x\neq 0$ and $0$ if $x=0$ where this was not the case.

I appreciante any insights on this problem.

Comment: You need to use a remainder formula. The easiest one to use in this context is probably the Lagrange remainder formula.

Comment: You can't uniformly bound all derivatives of your example function.

Comment: Your assumption $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq L$ is very strong, as it implies that
$$
\lvert \sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}\rvert \leq L\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|x-x_0|^n}{n!}=L e^{|x-x_0|}.
$$

Comment: I think that the Lagrange formula will do the trick, thank you.